# I receive application define object defined error while inserting bloomberg BDP formula to a cell

Tags: excel, bloomberg, defined

I get  application defined error while inserting a formula that is run by bloomberg addin.

```
Worksheets("Portfoy").Cells(portfoyCounter, 10).Formula = "=BDP(" & Chr(34) & Worksheets("Portfoy").Cells(portfoyCounter , 3).Value & " ISIN" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "YAS_RISK" & Chr(34) & ")*100*"
```

This code should insert =BDP("XS1634372954 ISIN";"YAS_RISK")*100 this to the cell `(portfoyCounter, 10)` and XS1634372954  is located in `Cells(portfoyCounter , 3)`

portfoyCounter variable holds the correct row count I have checked it. I have tried above code in the same manner in different code blocks without any issue but I do not know why I get that error this time.

Tnx vm for you Help in advance.

I checked the counter values but it seems correct.

Comment: Instead of `"=BDP(" & Chr(34) & "xxx" & Chr(34)`, you can use `"=BDP(""xxx""` (doubling the double quotes). I suggest you put the right hand side of the expression in a variable and put a watch on it to inspect the value and make sure it is what you expect. Finally, there is a trailing star in your expression which looks suspicious.

Comment: Yes you are right I have inserted a star accidently in the and that was causing the error. Now it is working perfect. Tnx very much for your help.  I could not see  it and it really cost me time. you solved my issue tnx vm.